# Sharepoint client object model {File not found}

Tags: development, client-object-model

```
var onlineCredentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(ServiceUserName,securePassword);
var context = new ClientContext(clientUrl);
context.Credentials = onlineCredentials;
ar cc = GetAllFiles(sourceDir); //- get the files
int errorLog = 0;
foreach (string path in cc)
{
    var filepath = "";
    var sub_folder = new FileInfo(path).Directory.FullName;
    filepath = sub_folder.Split(new[] { sourceDir }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1];
    sub_folder = sub_folder.Split(new[] { sourceDir }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1].Replace("\\", "//");

    try
    {
        var folder = CreateFolder(context.Web, listname, sub_folder);//--- Create folder

        Web web = context.Web;
        FileCreationInformation newFile = new FileCreationInformation();
        newFile.Content = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);

        newFile.Url = filepath + "\\" + Path.GetFileName(path);
        List docs = web.Lists.GetByTitle(listname);
        Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File uploadFile = docs.RootFolder.Files.Add(newFile);
        context.Load(uploadFile);
        context.ExecuteQuery();

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.IO.File.AppendAllText(ErrorLogPath, e.Message);

    }
}
```

I am trying to upload my local files to SharePoint using c#. If folder is not in 
**Document Libraray** , its creating the folders and sub-folders. But, It's not uploading the files.
In Exception, getting the following error:

> Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client.ServerException : {File not Found}

**Note:**

1. User having Full Admin Permissions.
2. If I Change user permission from Admin To Normal, getting error

   > Access is denied

   But folders were created.
3. In VS,"Platform target:" is "Any CPU".

Create Folder Function:

```
public static Folder CreateFolder(Web web, string listTitle, string fullFolderPath)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fullFolderPath))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("fullFolderPath");
        var list = web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);
        return CreateFolderInternal(web, list.RootFolder, fullFolderPath);
    }
private static Folder CreateFolderInternal(Web web, Folder parentFolder, string fullFolderPath)
    {
        var folderUrls = fullFolderPath.Split(new char[] { '/' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        string folderUrl = folderUrls[0];
        var curFolder = parentFolder.Folders.Add(folderUrl);
        web.Context.Load(curFolder);
        web.Context.ExecuteQuery();

        if (folderUrls.Length > 1)
        {
            var folderPath = string.Join("/", folderUrls, 1, folderUrls.Length - 1);
            return CreateFolderInternal(web, curFolder, folderPath);
        }
        return curFolder;
    }
```

It's creating Folder, no issue in creating folder. Only i couldn't upload a file.

Comment: We need to see your `CreateFolder` method

Comment: Did you really think that adding a method that just calls another "secret" method would help? ;)

Comment: @Praven Try doing a file upload without first creating the folders. Does that work? If not, then your question can become much simpler/easier to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are all sorted with your file paths, I would suggest you to update the list first before updating the listItem.

```
newFile.Url = filepath + "\\" + Path.GetFileName(path);
List docs = web.Lists.GetByTitle(listname);
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File uploadFile = docs.RootFolder.Files.Add(newFile);

context.Load(docs);        //Update the list where the file is being uploaded

context.Load(uploadFile);
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

That being said, do verify that your paths are coming correctly.